# Openshift application cannot start

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, openshift, jboss-eap-6

I have Java EE application deployed to Openshift. It is created from example and modified. I deployed application and worked fine, then I changes 3 css files, pushed to Openshift, but from that time application is not running. I tried restart (sometimes tells me could not restart, sometimes restarted), but no result - application is displaying blank page or 503 error. What could be a problem? On my local system, app is working fine, using MySQL DB. And MySQL is running on Openshif, I can connect to it.

URL:
http://gympel.mojefotogalerie.com/

How can I download some log files from Openshift to look at? Or what could be the reason while before that change (only 3 css files changed) everything went well?

**C:\Users\Marek>rhc tail gympel**

```
==> app-root/logs/jbosseap.log <==
  JBOSS_HOME: /var/lib/openshift/542a6df0e0b8cdee1a00016b/jbosseap
  JAVA: /etc/alternatives/java_sdk_1.6.0/bin/java
  JAVA_OPTS:  -server -XX:+TieredCompilation -Xms40m -Xmx256m -XX:MaxPermSize=10
2m -XX:+AggressiveOpts -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=20 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=40 -XX:GCTim
eRatio=4 -XX:AdaptiveSizePolicyWeight=90 -Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.LOW_MEMORY=tru
e -DOPENSHIFT_APP_UUID=542a6df0e0b8cdee1a00016b -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=tru
e -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djboss.node.name=gympel
-marek71cz.rhcloud.com -Djgroups.bind_addr=127.8.71.129 -Dorg.apache.coyote.http
11.Http11Protocol.COMPRESSION=on
=========================================================================
=========================================================================
  JBoss Bootstrap Environment
  JBOSS_HOME: /var/lib/openshift/542a6df0e0b8cdee1a00016b/jbosseap
  JAVA: /etc/alternatives/java_sdk_1.6.0/bin/java
  JAVA_OPTS:  -server -XX:+TieredCompilation -Xms40m -Xmx256m -XX:MaxPermSize=10
2m -XX:+AggressiveOpts -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=20 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=40 -XX:GCTim
eRatio=4 -XX:AdaptiveSizePolicyWeight=90 -Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.LOW_MEMORY=tru
e -DOPENSHIFT_APP_UUID=542a6df0e0b8cdee1a00016b -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=tru
e -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djboss.node.name=gympel
-marek71cz.rhcloud.com -Djgroups.bind_addr=127.8.71.129 -Dorg.apache.coyote.http
11.Http11Protocol.COMPRESSION=on
=========================================================================

==> app-root/logs/mysql.log <==
140930 10:49:30 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
140930 10:49:30  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
140930 10:49:31 InnoDB: 5.5.37 started; log sequence number 1699425
140930 10:49:31 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.8.71.130'; port: 330
6
140930 10:49:31 [Note]   - '127.8.71.130' resolves to '127.8.71.130';
140930 10:49:31 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.8.71.130'.
140930 10:49:31 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@ex-std-node449.prod.rhclo
ud.com' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
140930 10:49:31 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
140930 10:49:31 [Note] /opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connec
tions.
Version: '5.5.37'  socket: '/var/lib/openshift/542a6df0e0b8cdee1a00016b/mysql//s
ocket/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

**And this is content of my jbosseap.log file**

```
=========================================================================
  JBoss Bootstrap Environment
  JBOSS_HOME: /var/lib/openshift/542a6df0e0b8cdee1a00016b/jbosseap
  JAVA: /etc/alternatives/java_sdk_1.6.0/bin/java
  JAVA_OPTS:  -server -XX:+TieredCompilation -Xms40m -Xmx256m -XX:MaxPermSize=102m -XX:+AggressiveOpts -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=20 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=40 -XX:GCTimeRatio=4 -XX:AdaptiveSizePolicyWeight=90 -Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.LOW_MEMORY=true -DOPENSHIFT_APP_UUID=542a6df0e0b8cdee1a00016b -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djboss.node.name=gympel-marek71cz.rhcloud.com -Djgroups.bind_addr=127.8.71.129 -Dorg.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.COMPRESSION=on
=========================================================================
2014/09/30 04:49:12,911 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.3.4.Final-redhat-1
2014/09/30 04:49:13,964 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.1.5.Final-redhat-1
2014/09/30 04:49:14,194 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015899: JBoss EAP 6.3.1.GA (AS 7.4.1.Final-redhat-3) starting
2014/09/30 04:49:17,554 WARN  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS011608: Element CLUSTERED is deprecated and will not be taken into account
2014/09/30 04:49:18,407 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 14) JBAS014627: Attribute clustered is deprecated, and it might be removed in future version!
2014/09/30 04:49:18,457 WARN  [org.jboss.messaging] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 14) JBAS011618: There is no resource matching the expiry-address jms.queue.ExpiryQueue for the address-settings #, expired messages from destinations matching this address-setting will be lost!
2014/09/30 04:49:18,461 WARN  [org.jboss.messaging] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 14) JBAS011619: There is no resource matching the dead-letter-address jms.queue.DLQ for the address-settings #, undelivered messages from destinations matching this address-setting will be lost!
2014/09/30 04:49:18,551 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-2) XNIO Version 3.0.10.GA-redhat-1
2014/09/30 04:49:18,556 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015883: No security realm defined for native management service; all access will be unrestricted.
2014/09/30 04:49:18,600 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-2) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.10.GA-redhat-1
2014/09/30 04:49:18,605 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
2014/09/30 04:49:18,605 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015884: No security realm defined for http management service; all access will be unrestricted.
2014/09/30 04:49:18,688 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBoss Remoting version 3.3.3.Final-redhat-1
=========================================================================
  JBoss Bootstrap Environment
  JBOSS_HOME: /var/lib/openshift/542a6df0e0b8cdee1a00016b/jbosseap
  JAVA: /etc/alternatives/java_sdk_1.6.0/bin/java
  JAVA_OPTS:  -server -XX:+TieredCompilation -Xms40m -Xmx256m -XX:MaxPermSize=102m -XX:+AggressiveOpts -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=20 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=40 -XX:GCTimeRatio=4 -XX:AdaptiveSizePolicyWeight=90 -Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.LOW_MEMORY=true -DOPENSHIFT_APP_UUID=542a6df0e0b8cdee1a00016b -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djboss.node.name=gympel-marek71cz.rhcloud.com -Djgroups.bind_addr=127.8.71.129 -Dorg.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.COMPRESSION=on
=========================================================================
=========================================================================
  JBoss Bootstrap Environment
  JBOSS_HOME: /var/lib/openshift/542a6df0e0b8cdee1a00016b/jbosseap
  JAVA: /etc/alternatives/java_sdk_1.6.0/bin/java
  JAVA_OPTS:  -server -XX:+TieredCompilation -Xms40m -Xmx256m -XX:MaxPermSize=102m -XX:+AggressiveOpts -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=20 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=40 -XX:GCTimeRatio=4 -XX:AdaptiveSizePolicyWeight=90 -Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.LOW_MEMORY=true -DOPENSHIFT_APP_UUID=542a6df0e0b8cdee1a00016b -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djboss.node.name=gympel-marek71cz.rhcloud.com -Djgroups.bind_addr=127.8.71.129 -Dorg.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.COMPRESSION=on
=========================================================================
=========================================================================
  JBoss Bootstrap Environment
  JBOSS_HOME: /var/lib/openshift/542a6df0e0b8cdee1a00016b/jbosseap
  JAVA: /etc/alternatives/java_sdk_1.6.0/bin/java
  JAVA_OPTS:  -server -XX:+TieredCompilation -Xms40m -Xmx256m -XX:MaxPermSize=102m -XX:+AggressiveOpts -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=20 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=40 -XX:GCTimeRatio=4 -XX:AdaptiveSizePolicyWeight=90 -Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.LOW_MEMORY=true -DOPENSHIFT_APP_UUID=542a6df0e0b8cdee1a00016b -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djboss.node.name=gympel-marek71cz.rhcloud.com -Djgroups.bind_addr=127.8.71.129 -Dorg.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.COMPRESSION=on
=========================================================================
=========================================================================
  JBoss Bootstrap Environment
  JBOSS_HOME: /var/lib/openshift/542a6df0e0b8cdee1a00016b/jbosseap
  JAVA: /etc/alternatives/java_sdk_1.6.0/bin/java
  JAVA_OPTS:  -server -XX:+TieredCompilation -Xms40m -Xmx256m -XX:MaxPermSize=102m -XX:+AggressiveOpts -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=20 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=40 -XX:GCTimeRatio=4 -XX:AdaptiveSizePolicyWeight=90 -Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.LOW_MEMORY=true -DOPENSHIFT_APP_UUID=542a6df0e0b8cdee1a00016b -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djboss.node.name=gympel-marek71cz.rhcloud.com -Djgroups.bind_addr=127.8.71.129 -Dorg.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.COMPRESSION=on
=========================================================================
=========================================================================
  JBoss Bootstrap Environment
  JBOSS_HOME: /var/lib/openshift/542a6df0e0b8cdee1a00016b/jbosseap
  JAVA: /etc/alternatives/java_sdk_1.6.0/bin/java
  JAVA_OPTS:  -server -XX:+TieredCompilation -Xms40m -Xmx256m -XX:MaxPermSize=102m -XX:+AggressiveOpts -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=20 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=40 -XX:GCTimeRatio=4 -XX:AdaptiveSizePolicyWeight=90 -Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.LOW_MEMORY=true -DOPENSHIFT_APP_UUID=542a6df0e0b8cdee1a00016b -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djboss.node.name=gympel-marek71cz.rhcloud.com -Djgroups.bind_addr=127.8.71.129 -Dorg.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.COMPRESSION=on
=========================================================================
=========================================================================
  JBoss Bootstrap Environment
  JBOSS_HOME: /var/lib/openshift/542a6df0e0b8cdee1a00016b/jbosseap
  JAVA: /etc/alternatives/java_sdk_1.6.0/bin/java
  JAVA_OPTS:  -server -XX:+TieredCompilation -Xms40m -Xmx256m -XX:MaxPermSize=102m -XX:+AggressiveOpts -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=20 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=40 -XX:GCTimeRatio=4 -XX:AdaptiveSizePolicyWeight=90 -Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.LOW_MEMORY=true -DOPENSHIFT_APP_UUID=542a6df0e0b8cdee1a00016b -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djboss.node.name=gympel-marek71cz.rhcloud.com -Djgroups.bind_addr=127.8.71.129 -Dorg.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.COMPRESSION=on
=========================================================================
=========================================================================
  JBoss Bootstrap Environment
  JBOSS_HOME: /var/lib/openshift/542a6df0e0b8cdee1a00016b/jbosseap
  JAVA: /etc/alternatives/java_sdk_1.6.0/bin/java
  JAVA_OPTS:  -server -XX:+TieredCompilation -Xms40m -Xmx256m -XX:MaxPermSize=102m -XX:+AggressiveOpts -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=20 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=40 -XX:GCTimeRatio=4 -XX:AdaptiveSizePolicyWeight=90 -Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.LOW_MEMORY=true -DOPENSHIFT_APP_UUID=542a6df0e0b8cdee1a00016b -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djboss.node.name=gympel-marek71cz.rhcloud.com -Djgroups.bind_addr=127.8.71.129 -Dorg.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.COMPRESSION=on
=========================================================================
=========================================================================
  JBoss Bootstrap Environment
  JBOSS_HOME: /var/lib/openshift/542a6df0e0b8cdee1a00016b/jbosseap
  JAVA: /etc/alternatives/java_sdk_1.6.0/bin/java
  JAVA_OPTS:  -server -XX:+TieredCompilation -Xms40m -Xmx256m -XX:MaxPermSize=102m -XX:+AggressiveOpts -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=20 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=40 -XX:GCTimeRatio=4 -XX:AdaptiveSizePolicyWeight=90 -Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.LOW_MEMORY=true -DOPENSHIFT_APP_UUID=542a6df0e0b8cdee1a00016b -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djboss.node.name=gympel-marek71cz.rhcloud.com -Djgroups.bind_addr=127.8.71.129 -Dorg.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.COMPRESSION=on
=========================================================================
```

**And finally I managed to download server log and I san see out of memory error**

```
2014/09/30 18:15:21,894 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS011401: Read persistence.xml for primary
2014/09/30 18:15:21,926 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-42 (HornetQ-scheduled-threads-4300596)) Exception in thread "Thread-42 (HornetQ-scheduled-threads-4300596)" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
2014/09/30 18:15:21,926 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-42 (HornetQ-scheduled-threads-4300596))  at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
2014/09/30 18:15:21,927 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-42 (HornetQ-scheduled-threads-4300596))  at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:679)
2014/09/30 18:15:21,927 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-42 (HornetQ-scheduled-threads-4300596))  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:950)
2014/09/30 18:15:21,927 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-42 (HornetQ-scheduled-threads-4300596))  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.processWorkerExit(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1018)
2014/09/30 18:15:21,927 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-42 (HornetQ-scheduled-threads-4300596))  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1164)
2014/09/30 18:15:21,927 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-42 (HornetQ-scheduled-threads-4300596))  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
2014/09/30 18:15:21,927 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-42 (HornetQ-scheduled-threads-4300596))  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Try using the rhc tail command to view your logs, or ssh into your gear and look in the ~/app-root/logs directory, and then post your errors in your original question

Comment: Thanks for reply, I added some logs and I think the most interesting is the last one - server log. I can see i am running out of memory, "unable to create new native thread".

Answer (score 0):

If you are running out of memory you need to use a larger gear, are you running on the small gear? Java can eat up 512MB of ram pretty quickly, especially if you are running a database on the same gear, you could also do a scaled application and put the db on it's own gear, that might help some...

Comment: I understand, but it sounds strange. I have small gear and MYSQL database. But it is realy small application (maybe 10-15 classes and 5 jsps) using spring and the database has three tables with only a few rows in them. Other application which is very similar is working fine...

Comment: You might try finding a good java profiling tool and run it on both of your programs and see how much memory they are using.